# Why php curl works from command line and doesn't within Apache?

Tags: php, linux, curl, proxy

My CentOS machine is behind company's proxy and has **http proxy** set system-wide. Running **curl** from command line does not require proxy settings and returns output.

```
curl http://google.com
```

However, using this example:

```
$url = 'http://google.com';
try{
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
        $curl_scraped_page = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);

         header('Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
        echo $curl_scraped_page;
} catch (Exception $ex)
{
        echo $ex->getMessage();
}
?>
```

I get: **Connection timed out**

I know there is **CURLOPT_PROXY** option I can add to the code.

But why would I need it **if proxy is set system-wide**?

**In short:**

Launching this php script from Apache:

```
http://myserver.com/test_curl.php
```

does not work.

However running it via command line:

```
php test_curl.php
```

... works.

Why? What's the difference?

Comment: `cat ~/.curlrc` contains info about proxy?

Comment: Nope. But confg in this file is mainly used by curl command line tool. Not the actual library that php is using.